# Add Text DataBinding for CTabItem

Tags: java, swt, e4

I have a [CTabItem](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCTabItem.html) on a CTabFolder and want to bind its text to a StyledText Widget.
The API says WidgetProperties.text() can be used with an Item and CTabItem implements an Item.
So in my opinion [WidgetProperties.text()](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdatabinding%2Fswt%2FWidgetProperties.html) should work with CTabItem as well, but it doesn´t. Even if I cast the CTabItem to an Item.
Can someone explain to me why and how I can bind the CTabItem´s text to a StyledText?

This is a code Snippet of what I tried to do:

```
private void addDataBindingForItem(CTabItem stageItem, Stage stage) {
     DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();

     IObservableValue observableModelStageName = BeanProperties.value(
     Stage.class, "stageName").observe(stage);
     Item castedStageItem = (Item) stageItem;
     IObservableValue observableWidgetStageName = WidgetProperties.text(
     SWT.Modify).observe(castedStageItem);
     ctx.bindValue(observableWidgetStageName, observableModelStageName);
}
```

OT: Sorry I cant post more than two links until I get 10 rep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `WidgetProperties.text(int)` which the JavaDoc says is for `StyledText` or `Text`.

`WidgetProperties.text()` supports `Item`:

```
IObservableValue observableWidgetStageName = WidgetProperties.text().observe(stageItem);
```

Comment: Oh, my mistake.Thanks greg!